# How to set Heroku node memory to use 14GB for Performance L Dyno

Tags: node.js, heroku, memory, scaling, ram

I recently upgraded to a Performance L dyno for my node app because I needed more resources, but I've had a hard time figuring out how to utilize the 14GB of available ram.

[image: Memory graph]

I've tried to set the `WEB_MEMORY` env var in heroku and I've also tried to set the node flag `--max-old-space-size` in my start command.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have currently memory leaks?

Comment: How many clusters do you have? And version of nodejs

Comment: Did you try `--optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=xxx`?

Comment: I don't have any memory leaks. I'll try `--optimize_for_size` again. I have 18 web clusters.

Comment: @Artur Just tried `--optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=xxx` and still not working

Comment: I dont have idea. Maybe your code is optimised and dont use full memory because does not need it?
Did you tried perform tests and fill all avaliable buffer?